# Google Map XML markers

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display some markers on a Google Map using an XML file.

I seem to be able to get the markers to display OK but I want to know how I can filter them down.

The XML in question is like the below;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OutageData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TimeStamp>2014-01-24T11:33:41.665165+00:00</TimeStamp>
  <Outages>
    <Outage>
      <Region>South West</Region>
      <IncidentID>INCD-30315-k</IncidentID>
      <ConfirmedOff>4</ConfirmedOff>
      <PredictedOff>0</PredictedOff>
      <Restored>0</Restored>
      <Status>In Progress</Status>
      <Planned>false</Planned>
      <StartTime>2014-01-24T09:30:00</StartTime>
      <ETR xsi:nil="true" />
      <Voltage>LV</Voltage>
      <PostCodes>
        <string>TR20 8UJ</string>
      </PostCodes>
      <Sensitive>0</Sensitive>
      <Location lat="50.13206" lng="-5.5528" />
    </Outage>
    <Outage>
      <Region>South West</Region>
      <IncidentID>INCD-30342-k</IncidentID>
      <ConfirmedOff>7</ConfirmedOff>
      <PredictedOff>0</PredictedOff>
      <Restored>0</Restored>
      <Status>In Progress</Status>
      <Planned>true</Planned>
      <StartTime>2014-01-24T09:00:00</StartTime>
      <ETR xsi:nil="true" />
      <Voltage>LV</Voltage>
      <PostCodes>
        <string>TR4 8AL</string>
        <string>TR4 8AN</string>
        <string>TR4 8AP</string>
        <string>TR4 8AW</string>
        <string>TR4 8FE</string>
      </PostCodes>
      <Sensitive>4</Sensitive>
      <Location lat="50.28881" lng="-5.236961" />
    </Outage>
</Outages>
</OutageData>
```

However I only want to display markers where the Planned value is 'false'.
So from the data above, only one marker should show on the map.

The code I am currently using is jQuery code;

```
jQuery.get("/dataNew.xml", {}, function (data) {
        jQuery(data).find("Outage").each(function () {

                $(this).find("Location").each(function () {
                    var marker = jQuery(this);
                    var latlngNew = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.attr("lat")),
                                            parseFloat(marker.attr("lng")));
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlngNew, map: map });
                });

        });
    });
```

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative.

Kind regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the value of the planned node each time in an if you can simply stop the plotting of points you don't want. Something like: (untested)

```
jQuery.get("/dataNew.xml", {}, function (data) {
    jQuery(data).find("Outage").each(function () {
            if($(this).find("Planned").text() == "true")
            {
                $(this).find("Location").each(function () {
                    var marker = jQuery(this);
                    var latlngNew = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(marker.attr("lat")),
                                           parseFloat(marker.attr("lng")));
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlngNew, map: map });
                });
            }

    });
});
```

Comment: I think I managed to get it going a similar way, but by creating the 'Planned' statement as a variable and adding this to the 'if' statement. This solution works just as well. Thank you for your help.